# F# library expected to behave like C# when consumed

Tags: c#, f#

I'm developing a library in F# for consumption by another team using C#.  What things should I  look out for knowing that this other team expects this library to behave like any other C# library?

For example if I use Options types I'll need to convert them to null when I expose to C#.  Some other possible transition areas could be computation expressions, FastFunc, events and naming issues.

Comment: Some<T> and None translate into Nullable<T>, more or less.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf) is a document designed to answer exactly this question.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't expose any of the F# types, especially lists, maps, etc (exposing something of type `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpMap` will surely make the C# team go nuts). When you're exposing a getter or a return type that is a F# collection, call `List.toSeq` and you'll end up with an `IEnumerable`, which is much nicer to work with in C#.

Other than that, you should be just fine. I've used F# and C# on only 1 project before, and that was my only real issue/annoyance interoperating the two.